# Is it possible to auto generate database using two Context?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using **Entity Framework Code First** and **ASP.NET Identity**. In this case the ASP.NET related tables are auto generated when its `ApplicationDbContext` is used the first time.

The problem is that I wanted to create a separate DLL and use the same database and the new classes should create tables in the same Context.

I created a new `DbContext` and I'm using the same connection name.

Unfortunately EF does not understand that I want my `DbSet` tables in the same database as the `ApplicationDbContext`.

When It reaches a line of code where I'm using the tables I wanted be auto generated a message is shown saying this:

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException: 42P01: relation "public.Customers" does not exist

this is a sample code:

```
var customer1 = (from u in context.Customers
    where u.Id == 1234
    select u).ToList();
```

Is it possible to use auto generation of the database in EF Code First with more than one `DbContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Here's a slightly old tutorial:

**Entity Framework 6 Code First Migrations with Multiple Data Contexts**

- http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html

It specifies 2 scenarios: multiple DbContexts within the same project, and in separate projects.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. I did work. But unfortunately is far from what I thought it would be. My code ended up with a bunch of `string` that needs to be refactored manually. I think this time I will just stick with the "one db one Context" approach. But thanks again for your help.